# How to determine the LLVM version?

Tags: command-line, llvm

Hi I just downloaded LLVM using the command

```
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
```

How can I determine the version of this LLVM (4.0, 3.9 or 3.8 etc)?

Answer (score 29):

After installation, try running:

```
llvm-config  --version
```

Comment: also works for Windows

Answer (score 3):

You are checking out the trunk.

If you want a particular version checkout the appropriate branch.

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/branches/release_35

would be llvm-3.5

Answer (score 1):

On **Windows 10** you enter in the terminal (`cmd.exe`)

```
llvm-cov --version
```

```
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin>llvm-cov --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 16.0.0
  Optimized build.
```

This works with some other *.exe from `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin` as well (e. g. `clang --version`)

Note: I installed LLVM-16.0.0-win64.exe from https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-16.0.0 and added the installation path `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin` to the (local) PATH variable.

If you don't have LLVM as PATH variable you need to include the path to the executable, too. In the terminal you enter (e. g.):

```
"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\llvm-cov.exe" --version
```